# Действительный и реальный

Tags: лексика

Слова «действительный и реальный, действительность и реальность» близки по смыслу: 
РЕАЛЬНЫЙ - существующий на самом деле, действительный, не воображаемый. 
ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЙ - существующий на самом деле; реальный, подлинный, настоящий.

Хотелось бы обсудить следующие вопросы:

1. Отличаются ли эти слова в современном языке  по значению и области применения?
2. Почему они появились только в 18-19 веке, а не раньше?
3. Почему семантика одного из них связана с действием, а другого – с  материей, с веществом?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

С точки зрения ФИЛОСОФИИ,  слова  «действительный и реальный» синонимичны: мир действительный, реальный, существующий противопоставляется    виртуальному,  придуманному, созданному воображением. Однако В ЖИЗНИ  область употребления этих слов различается:

ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЙ.  Синонимы: настоящий, действующий, юридически законный.  Антонимы:  формальный, желаемый.

РЕАЛЬНЫЙ. Синонимы:  проверенный опытом,  существующий в жизни, действенный. Антонимы:  придуманный,  виртуальный, пропагандистский.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В философии эти слова тоже различаются.

*Действительный* - относящийся к объективной реальности.

*Реальный* - относящийся к реальности, в том числе и виртуальной, вымышленной. Реальность бывает объективная (действительность), субъективная, физическая, биологическая, социальная, художественная и т. д. Реальность слоится, действительность всегда одна.

Начиная с Аристотеля действительность трактуется как реализация возможностей, отождествляется с действенностью, актом.

В нем. языке термин «действительность» (Wirklichkeit) как перевод лат. слова «actualitas» («действенность») был введен Мейстером Экхартом. В нем. языке в понятии «действительность» содержится, следовательно, важный компонент действия, в то время как в древнегреч. и лат. действительность идентична с истинностью, а во франц. и англ. – с реальностью. В нем. языке истинность отличается от действительности тем, что она связана с очевидностью (но не с действием), а реальность от действительности – тем, что в ней содержится также и возможное.

Comment: Сочетание "виртуальная реальность" появилось лет 30 назад. И ещё не укоренилось настолько, чтоб "обратным ходом" повлиять на смысл слова "реальный". Может быть, в будущем...

Comment: Виртуальное соединилось именно с тем словом, которое к этому располагало, - не с действительностью, которая одна, а с реальностью, которых много.

Comment: Вообще-то данное выражение изначально рассматривалось как оксюморн (соединение несоединимого). И только развитие компьютерной техники "наделило" его "самостоятельной жизнью".

Answer (score 4):

Действительность и реальность - синонимы, но противопоставляются они разным вещам. Реальный значит не воображаемый, действительный - не ложный. "В **действительности** Пьер Безухов и Наташа Ростова поженились", - вполне можем сказать мы, описывая сюжет романа Толстого, хотя в **реальности** этих людей никогда не существовало. Это ответ на ваш первый вопрос.

Из ответа на первый вопрос вытекает и ответ на второй. Потому что была "правда" и была "ложь", о том что между правдой и ложью может находится "правдивая ложь" и " ложная правда"  человек с чёрно-белым религиозным восприятием мира даже не догадывался. Сказка - именно *ложь*, хоть и безобидная, а всё что правда - существует. В XVIII-XIX вв под воздействием французской и немецкой литературы, и прежде всего философии, мир стал более разнообразным, потребовалось разделить реальность от воображения, а мир от наших представлений о нём. Из этих посылов и родились рассматриваемые слова.

Ну, а чтобы ответить на третий вопрос нужно понимать немецкую классическую философию, что явно выходит за рамки филологического форума. "Действительность"  - это калька с немецкого "Wirklichkeit". Если очень кратко, и потому не совсем точно рассматриваемые понятия показывают разный подход к восприятию мира: мир как статичная картина - "реальность", мир как непрерывное действие - "действительность".

Comment: Слово реальный восходит к средневек. латин. realis –вещественный. Получается, что  словом «действительный» немецкие философы в противовес статичной материи обозначили материю движущуюся? В русский язык сначала вошло слово «действительный» (нач. 18 века), а потом в середине 19 века вспомнили о «реальном». Может быть, просто потребовался синоним, или  здесь другая причина?

Comment: @София, Действительный в начале  XVIII века и действительный в конце - это разные слова.  Существительное "действительность" - это уже немецкая философия. Потребность в "реальности" появляется с дальнейшим развитием знаний о мире. Появляется Фейербах, Маркс, поэтому и понятие Реальности тоже становится необходимым.

Comment: Термин "реальность" появился в 13 в. у схоластов применительно к вещам, обладающим "значительной степенью" бытия, а в наибольшей мере – к богу как "полноте бытия".

Answer (score 2):

Судя по ответам,  вопрос оказался сложнее, чем мыслилось вначале, и отчасти приобрел философский характер.  Пришлось задумываться о вещах, которые раньше не попадали в поле зрения. Итак, реальность и действительность, в чем их сходство и различие?

1) РЕАЛЬНОСТЬ – это среда с определенными свойствами. Мы можем говорить о реальностях, различающихся своим энергетическим уровнем:  физический мир, ментальный мир.  Реальность может быть тематической:  окружающая, российская, художественная и др.  Мы можем  придумать (сконструировать)   для себя реальность,  задав ей  какие-то  свойства, и даже существовать в ней.  Во всех этих случаях реальность  получает разнообразные определения:  новая, другая, собственная, проявленная, непроявленная. Если никакого определения нет, то мыслится физическая реальность, которая в этом значении совпадает с действительностью.

2) Но что такое ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНОСТЬ? Очень интересная и сложная история и у понятия,  и у слова. Поэтому неудивительно, что люди по-разному понимают эту категорию. Действительность может иметь различные определения: наша, окружающая, сегодняшняя, суровая, обывательская, советская, но при этом  ее фундаментальные свойства как-то не затрагиваются. (Можно предположить, что они  имеют постоянный характер).

Возможно, прав был В.И. Жуковский, который  полагал,  что «если под реальностью понимать мир вещей (лат. realis — «вещественный»), то действительность — это мир вещей, с которым действуют (лат. dei — «деятель»)». Поэтому можно считать, что действительный мир – это тот, с которым можно ВЗАИМОДЕЙСТВОВАТЬ, который  способен проявить  ответную реакцию на ваши манипуляции по принципу «действие равно противодействию».

Из истории слов (интересный материал по теме: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/50/ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЙ

Answer (score 0):

> > 1. Отличаются ли эти слова в современном языке по значению и области применения?

А как же... Достаточно посмотреть в толковый словарь. *Реальная задача, реальный план.* "Вы даете нереальные планы!" - сказал герой Вицина из известного фильма. *Реально смотреть на вещи.* "Действительный" не подойдет.
*Пропуск действителен в течение суток* - а здесь "реальный" не подойдет.
И так далее.

> > 1. Почему семантика одного из них связана с действием, а другого – с материей, с веществом?

Действительно, почему? В страшном сне не приснится... Абсолютно нет.

Answer (score 0):

Словари подсказывают, что "действительный" - "калька" с немецкого, а "реальный" - прямое заимствование из ново-латинского. Рассматривать семантику этих слов следует в языках происхождения.

В современном значении эти слова являются синонимами только в одной паре значений ("объективно существующий"). Остальные значения этих слов - разные. Почему так получилось? Сложный вопрос.. Видимо, дело в том, что эти слова проделали разный путь. "Реальный" длительное время использовалось в качестве "практический" ("реальное училище"). "Действительный" - как синоним слову "правильный" ("действительное значение")...

Comment: "Действительное значение"  — это совсем не "правильный", а именно что "объективно существующий". По крайней мере, если речь идет о технике.

Comment: Возможно, ошибся.. Подбирал выражение наспех.